# Php reference array with == comparison strange behaviour

Tags: php

I have this Array : `[-1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2]`
and this function :

```
function removeDuplicates(&$nums) {
    $len = count($nums);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $elem = $nums[$i];
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $len; $j++) {
            // Line X
            if ($elem === $nums[$j]) {
                unset($nums[$j]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In line X if I put `==` the result will be : `[-1,1,2]` missing a 0
with `===` the result is : `[-1,0,1,2]`
Could someone help me understand why ?

Comment: Look at [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Also look into [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: yeah but they are of the same type , it gives the same result with $nums[$i] === $nums[$j], and $nums[$i] == $nums[$j] and they are of the same type, i know about array_unique ,actually it's an exercice for complexity

Comment: It's actually nothing to do with the typecasting, but the errors it's throwing. https://3v4l.org/8WebU -- I had to add some checks to make sure the array key existed. Here's the version with the errors - https://3v4l.org/k2akB